# Action failed with 'security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized for user

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to install elastic search and kibana on windows machine.
After starting elastic search elastic search is working fine. But if i started kibana server it showing below erros:

```
[2022-07-08T17:21:28.195+05:30][INFO ][savedobjects-service] Starting saved objects migrations
[2022-07-08T17:21:28.231+05:30][INFO ][savedobjects-service] [.kibana] INIT -> CREATE_NEW_TARGET. took: 18ms.
[2022-07-08T17:21:28.235+05:30][INFO ][savedobjects-service] [.kibana_task_manager] INIT -> CREATE_NEW_TARGET. took: 20ms.
[2022-07-08T17:21:28.245+05:30][ERROR][savedobjects-service] [.kibana_task_manager] Action failed with 'security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized for user [kunal] with roles [monitoring,network,admins,demorole] on restricted indices [.kibana_task_manager_8.3.2_001], this action is granted by the index privileges [create_index,manage,all]'. Retrying attempt 1 in 2 seconds.
[2022-07-08T17:21:28.246+05:30][INFO ][savedobjects-service] [.kibana_task_manager] CREATE_NEW_TARGET -> CREATE_NEW_TARGET. took: 10ms.
[2022-07-08T17:21:28.248+05:30][ERROR][savedobjects-service] [.kibana] Action failed with 'security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized for user [kunal] with roles [monitoring,network,admins,demorole] on restricted indices [.kibana_8.3.2_001], this action is granted by the index privileges [create_index,manage,all]'. Retrying attempt 1 in 2 seconds.
[2022-07-08T17:21:28.248+05:30][INFO ][savedobjects-service] [.kibana] CREATE_NEW_TARGET -> CREATE_NEW_TARGET. took: 18ms.
[2022-07-08T17:21:30.276+05:30][ERROR][savedobjects-service] [.kibana_task_manager] Action failed with 'security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized for user [kunal] with roles [monitoring,network,admins,demorole] on restricted indices [.kibana_task_manager_8.3.2_001], this action is granted by the index privileges [create_index,manage,all]'. Retrying attempt 2 in 4 seconds.
[2022-07-08T17:21:30.277+05:30][INFO ][savedobjects-service] [.kibana_task_manager] CREATE_NEW_TARGET -> CREATE_NEW_TARGET. took: 2031ms.
[2022-07-08T17:21:30.284+05:30][ERROR][savedobjects-service] [.kibana] Action failed with 'security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized for user [kunal] with roles [monitoring,network,admins,demorole] on restricted indices [.kibana_8.3.2_001], this action is granted by the index privileges [create_index,manage,all]'. Retrying attempt 2 in 4 seconds.
[2022-07-08T17:21:30.285+05:30][INFO ][savedobjects-service] [.kibana] CREATE_NEW_TARGET -> CREATE_NEW_TARGET. took: 2036ms.
[2022-07-08T17:21:34.311+05:30][ERROR][savedobjects-service] [.kibana_task_manager] Action failed with 'security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized for user [kunal] with roles [monitoring,network,admins,demorole] on restricted indices [.kibana_task_manager_8.3.2_001], this action is granted by the index privileges [create_index,manage,all]'. Retrying attempt 3 in 8 seconds.
[2022-07-08T17:21:34.313+05:30][INFO ][savedobjects-service] [.kibana_task_manager] CREATE_NEW_TARGET -> CREATE_NEW_TARGET. took: 4035ms.
[2022-07-08T17:21:34.321+05:30][ERROR][savedobjects-service] [.kibana] Action failed with 'security_exception: [security_exception] Reason: action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized for user [kunal] with roles [monitoring,network,admins,demorole] on restricted indices [.kibana_8.3.2_001], this action is granted by the index privileges [create_index,manage,all]'. Retrying attempt 3 in 8 seconds.
```

Please find my elastic search files:
**roles.yml**

```yaml
# The default roles file is empty as the preferred method of defining roles is
# through the API/UI. File based roles are useful in error scenarios when the
# API based roles may not be available.
admins:
  cluster:
    - all
  indices:
    - names:
        - "*"
      privileges:
        - all
devs:
  cluster:
    - manage
  indices:
    - names:
        - "*"
      privileges:
        - write
        - delete
        - create_index
```

**users_roles** file

```
monitoring:kunal
network:kunal
admins:kunal
```

I have using user kunal from kibana for authentication.

I am not able to figure out what is the permission error here because for **admins** user i have given all privliges.

Comment: Could you please provide your `kibana.yml` file please ?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

Delete `kibana.index` in your `kibana.yml` file.

## To solve

I feel like you have modified the default name for internal kibana index.
By default it is `.kibana` but your's `.kibana_task_manager_8.3.2_001`

Which lead me to believe.

1. you are using v `8.3.2`
2. you change the `kibana.index` setting

But this is deprecated. [[doc]](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.17/settings.html)

Also you have an [issue talking](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/119342) about this.

##### disclaimer:

I haven't seen you `kibana.yml` file.

Comment: I have basically the same error (apart from `...  user [kibanaserver] ...` which has the same privileges as in the Q). I'm using 8.3.2. I'm _not_ using `kibana.index` in my `kibana.yml`.

Comment: cont'd: Solved it. There were different `users_roles` and `roles.yml` in the configs of our 9 nodes across 3 servers.

Comment: I do not have kibana.yml but I see the same error

Answer (score 0):

Please check your ...\elasticsearch-8.3.2\config\elasticsearch.yml as well. Here's my configuration. Hope that helps.

```
# Enable security features

xpack.security.enabled: false

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:

enabled: false

keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:

enabled: false

verification_mode: certificate

keystore.path: certs/transport.p12

truststore.path: certs/transport.p12

# Create a new cluster with the current node only
# Additional nodes can still join the cluster later

cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["Node1"]
```